# Change employment contracts due to relocation

Tags: contracts, relocation, layoff

Our organisation is planning a a restructure that will involve relocating some staff to other sites, as well as outsourcing a major function to a sub-contractor.

I have been asked to:

Summarise how we should go about changing these contracts lawfully

Explain the requirements of redundancy law (for those that will be made redundant)

I am unsure where to start - I have some HR background but not a huge amount. I have been tasked with this as I have a family relationship with the owner of the business.

Answer (score 5):

Where to start (and finish!) is easy:

> Sorry, but I don't have enough experience to handle this. I strongly recommend you engage a consultant with the appropriate skills. I'm happy to help them out where necessary, but I'm afraid I can't take the lead on this.

Don't get involved in things which could get your employer sued unless you *really* know what you're doing.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the only option - and will likely end up with the OP on the redundancy list. OTOH you could try to "fake" it, and get dragged into court. Frankly, I'd take the third option and run to another job